# Google Maps - Identical values in all info windows

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Like many other people I'm finding identical values within my info windows. Alas, I've been using other posts in an attempt to troubleshoot. No luck.

Issue: Each of my infowindows shows the same values. Sigh.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    var markers = [];
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        scrollwheel: false,
        streetViewControl: true,
        panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
        //  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
        },

        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.898854, 134.091377)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

    setMarkers(map, beaches);

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "Loading..."
    });

    var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
        document.getElementById('pac-input'));
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
        /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
        marker.setMap(null);
    }

    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
    var image = {
        //url: 'assets/img/icon_pin.png',
        //size: new google.maps.Size(40, 52),
        //origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        //anchor: new google.maps.Point(26, 20)
    };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
    });

    markers.push(marker);
    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
});

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
        searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
    });
}

var beaches = [
    ['Auburn', -33.847113, 151.04485, 1, '100', 'Parramatta', 'Road', 'Auburn', 'NSW', '2144', '02 7837 9800', '06:00 - 22:00', '06:00 - 22:00'],
    ['Balgowlah Platinum', -33.79284, 151.26376, 2, 'Shop 67, 197-215', 'Condamine', 'Street', 'Balgowlah', 'NSW', '2093', '1300 55 77 99', '06:00 - 21:30', '06:00 - 21:30'],
    ['Bankstown', -33.931208, 151.02895, 3, 'Unit 1-2, 9', 'Chapel', 'Street', 'South Bankstown', 'NSW', '2200', '02 8707 4700', '06:00 - 22:00', '06:00 - 22:00']
    ['Bayside', -37.954768, 145.03128, 4, '241 - 245', 'Bay', 'Road', 'Highett', 'VIC', '3190', '03 9559 7400', '06:00 - 22:00', '06:00 - 22:00']
];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
    var image = {
        url: 'assets/img/icon_pin.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(40, 52),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(26, 20)
    };

    var shape = {
        coord: [1, 1, 1, 52, 40, 52, 40 , 1],
        type: 'poly'
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var beach = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            shape: shape
        });

        var contentString = '<div class="siteNotice"><h4>'+beach[0]+'</h4><p>'+beach[4]+' '+beach[5]+' '+beach[6]+' '+beach[7]+', '+beach[8]+', '+beach[9]+'</p><p><strong>Contact:</strong> '+beach[10]+'</p><p><strong>Opening Hours:</strong><br><span>Monday:</span> '+beach[11]+'<br><span>Tuesday:</span> '+beach[11]+'<br><span>Wednesday:</span> '+beach[11]+'<br><span>Thursday</span>: '+beach[11]+'<br><span>Friday:</span> '+beach[11]+'<br><span>Saturday</span>: '+beach[11]+'<br><span>Sunday:</span> '+beach[11]+'</p></div>';                

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {

            infowindow.setContent(contentString);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to create an array of info markers to hold the data.

```javascript
var markers = [];
function addMapLocation(map, lat, long, title, message) {
    var locationLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    var locationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: locationLatLong, map: map, title: title.trim() });

    attachMessage(locationMarker, message);
    markers.push(locationMarker);
}
function attachMessage(marker, message) {
    var locationInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: message });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () { locationInfo.open(marker.get('map'), marker); });
}
```

Comment: Adam, thanks for the feedback. Forgive my ignorance but I'm just not too sure where/how this code sits within my existing code? Thanks.

Comment: My ``addMapLocation`` is very similar (in concept) to your ``setMarkers``. There is a lot of code, but it should be easy to follow my javascript. [Take a look at a live example](http://licensees.texasagriculture.gov/) There will also be some utility functions that Google doesn't provide.